# creating a enlarged duplicate of the d3.js element onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

This is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/74qrC/18/

I am using `d3.js`.

what i am trying to do is when user clicks on any of the rectangles then the exact copy of rectangle but bigger in size(twice as much as bigger than the original rectangle) will be displayed below of them.

i had added onclick method and then i am created the bigger rectangle by getting the attributes of the old rectangle. But it is not working. please help me out

i am not sure how to do this... Please help me out...

```
var numVisible = 4;
var rectWidth = 100,
rectHeight = 100,
rectPadding = 2,
numRects = 10;

var clipWidth = numVisible * rectWidth + (numVisible - 1) * rectPadding,
clipHeight = rectHeight;

var width = (rectWidth * numRects) + ((numRects - 1) * rectPadding),
height = rectHeight;

var data = d3.range(numRects);
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data))
    .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width', clipWidth)
    .attr('height', clipHeight);
var bigRectContainer = d3.select('#bigRectContainer').append('svg')
    .attr('width', clipWidth*2)
    .attr('height', clipHeight*2);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip")
.append("rect")
    .attr("width", clipWidth)
    .attr("height", clipHeight);

var g = svg.append("g");
g.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
    .attr("class", "area").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr('x', xScale)
    .attr('width', rectWidth)
    .attr('height', rectHeight)
    .style('fill', d3.scale.category20());

var update = function(){
g.selectAll("rect")
    .transition().duration(500)
    .attr('x', xScale);
};

d3.select("#left").on("click", function(){ 
if(xScale.domain()[0] - 1 > -numVisible){
    xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] - 1, xScale.domain()[1] - 1]);
    update();
}else if(xScale.domain()[0] - 1 == -numVisible)
{
    xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] + numRects, xScale.domain()[1] + numRects]);
    update();
}
});

d3.select("#right").on("click", function(){ 
if(xScale.domain()[0] + 1 < numRects){
    xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] + 1, xScale.domain()[1] + 1]);
    update();
}else if(xScale.domain()[0] + 1 == numRects)
{
    xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] - numRects, xScale.domain()[1] - numRects]);
    update();
}
});


svg.selectAll("rect").on("click", function() {
    var littleRect = d3.select(this);
console.log(littleRect)

var bigRect = bigRectContainer.append("rect").attr("width", littleRect.attr("width") * 2)
    .attr("height", littleRect.attr("height") * 2)
});
```

Please help me out...

Comment: you want all rectangle bigger at a time ?

Comment: No, when i click on a certain rectangle, then i want to create a duplicate of the rectangle but bigger in size.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a click event listener on your rects using selection.on.  It will be invoked when a rect is clicked such that `this` will reference the clicked node.  You can use this to create a new rect with double the size.

```
g.selectAll("rects").on("click", function() {
    var littleRect = d3.select(this);

    bigRectContainer.select("rect").remove();
    bigRectContainer.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bigrect")
        .attr("width", littleRect.attr("width") * 2)
        .attr("height", littleRect.attr("height") * 2)
        .style("fill", litteRect.attr("fill"));
});
```

Comment: Thank You but Your code is not working. When i am copy & pasting Your code in my code, all the rectangles are disappearing.... Please edit in my jsfiddle code.... Thank You

Comment: Looks like I missed a closing bracket.  I've added it now.  With that said, this code is just to give you an idea of how it should work.  I haven't tested it in any way.  So you may need to touch it up yourself. You'll also notice I reference a selection called "bigRectContainer" which I'm assuming you set up elsewhere in your code to reference the container into which you want the larger rectangle added.

Comment: Still not working..When i am clicking it is not triggering the click event.... Please can You make your changes in the Jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. There were some errors in your code but i fixed...

```
var bigRectContainer = d3.select('#bigRectContainer').append('svg')
    .attr('width', clipWidth*2)
    .attr('height', clipHeight*2);
svg.selectAll("rect").on("click", function() {
var littleRect = d3.select(this);
console.log(littleRect)

var bigRect = bigRectContainer.append("rect").attr("width", littleRect.attr("width") * 2)
    .attr("height", littleRect.attr("height") * 2).style('fill', d3.scale.category20())
});
```

But Thank you...

Comment: I was just going to take another look at the fiddle when I saw this so I'm glad you got it figured out.  Be careful with your "fill" line because you are constructing a new color scale on each invocation so I think you're going to end up with the same color each time.  Also, you're not removing any previously added rectangles anywhere so you will keep adding new rectangles each time you click.  The old ones are probably hidden behind the new ones.